# Returning object in response instead of individual parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, t-sql, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Below is the current response format:

```
"data": [
    {
      "dealerCode": "",
      "productSerialNumber": "",
      "secondarySaleDate": "13-12-2023 00:00:00",
      "remarks": "",
      "isValid": "",
      "dealerCodeErrorMsg": "",
      "serialNumberErrorMsg": "",
      "saleDateErrorMsg": ""
    }
  ]
```

Format of the response that I want:

```
"data": [
    {
      "dealerCode": "",
      "productSerialNumber": "",
      "secondarySaleDate": "13-12-2023 00:00:00",
      "remarks": "",
      "isValid": "",
      "error": {
        "dealerCodeErrorMsg": "",
        "serialNumberErrorMsg": "",
        "saleDateErrorMsg": "" 
      }
    }
  ]
```

How can I send this Error object as a whole with the parameters ("dealerCodeErrorMsg", "serialNumberErrorMsg" and "saleDateErrorMsg") instead of sending these parameters individually in my response.
My current Response Model Looks something like:

```
public class ResultModel
 {
     public string? DealerCode { get; set; }
     public string? ProductSerialNumber { get; set; }
     public string? SecondarySaleDate { get; set; }
     public string? Remarks { get; set; }
     public string? IsValid { get; set; }
     public string? DealerCodeErrorMsg { get; set; }
     public string? SerialNumberErrorMsg { get; set; }
     public string? SaleDateErrorMsg { get; set; }
 }
```

And the sql script that returns these values:

```
insert into #tempShow
(
    DealerCode,      
    ProductSerialNumber,
    SecondarySaleDate,
    Remarks,
    IsValid,
    DealerCodeErrorMsg,
    SerialNumberErrorMsg,
    SaleDateErrorMsg
)
values
(
    @Dlr_Sap_Code,
    @SerialNo,
    @saledate,
    @Remark,
    @flag,
    @DealerRemark,
    @SerialRemark,
    @SaleDateRemark
);
select *from #tempShow
```

I tried changing the response model:

```
public class SP_SecondaryBulkInfo_Result
{
    public string? DealerCode { get; set; }
    public string? ProductSerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string? SecondarySaleDate { get; set; }
    public string? Remarks { get; set; }
    public string? IsValid { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public Error? Error { get; set; } = new Error ();
}

[NotMapped]
public class Error
{
    public string? DealerCodeErrorMsg { get; set; }
    public string? SerialNumberErrorMsg { get; set; }
    public string? SaleDateErrorMsg { get; set; }
}
```

But not sure how to do the mapping correctly

Comment: Can you post any attempts you've tried thus far? This can help steer you in the right direction. Given you're looking to change the structure of the _response_ back, might hint at what needs to be changed.

Comment: I tried changing the response model, not sure how to map the values (DealerCodeErrorMsg, SerialNumberErrorMsg, SaleDateErrorMsg) that my sql script returns, with parameters in the response model

Comment: How are you performing the transformation from SQL to your response model?

Comment: Running the stored procedure in my .net backend code connected with the db through Entity Framework "
var lst = _dealerRepository.SP_SecondaryBulkInfo(value.User_Id, serialNumberString, saleDateString, value.Device_Id, dealerCodeString).ToList();
"
where this stored procedure response type is ResultModel

Comment: You should separate out the object for the data returned back from the stored procedure and the response from your API. By doing so, you can construct your API response object however you prefer once the results are returned back.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered modifying your ResultModel to include an Error property?

```cs
public class ResultModel
{
    public string? DealerCode { get; set; }
    public string? ProductSerialNumber { get; set; }
    public string? SecondarySaleDate { get; set; }
    public string? Remarks { get; set; }
    public string? IsValid { get; set; }
    public Error? Error { get; set; } = new Error();
}

public class Error
{
    public string? DealerCodeErrorMsg { get; set; }
    public string? SerialNumberErrorMsg { get; set; }
    public string? SaleDateErrorMsg { get; set; }
}
```

Then, modify your SQL query to alias the columns and use a projection in your LINQ query:

```cs
var results = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<ResultModel>(
    @"insert into #tempShow
      (
          DealerCode,      
          ProductSerialNumber,
          SecondarySaleDate,
          Remarks,
          IsValid,
          DealerCodeErrorMsg,
          SerialNumberErrorMsg,
          SaleDateErrorMsg
      )
      values
      (
          @Dlr_Sap_Code,
          @SerialNo,
          @saledate,
          @Remark,
          @flag,
          @DealerRemark,
          @SerialRemark,
          @SaleDateRemark
      );
      select
          DealerCode,
          ProductSerialNumber,
          SecondarySaleDate,
          Remarks,
          IsValid,
          DealerCodeErrorMsg,
          SerialNumberErrorMsg,
          SaleDateErrorMsg
      from #tempShow")
    .ToList();
```

The SQL query results are directly mapped to ResultModel, and the Error property is populated with the appropriate values.

However, a mapping library like AutoMapper can handle the mapping between your SQL results and your model.

If you choose to use `AutoMapper` after the usual setup, something along these lines should work

```cs
using AutoMapper;

public class YourServiceOrController
{
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public YourServiceOrController(IMapper mapper)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
    }

    public List<ResultModel> GetResults()
    {
        var sqlResults = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<SP_SecondaryBulkInfo_Result>(
            @"insert into #tempShow
              (
                  DealerCode,      
                  ProductSerialNumber,
                  SecondarySaleDate,
                  Remarks,
                  IsValid,
                  DealerCodeErrorMsg,
                  SerialNumberErrorMsg,
                  SaleDateErrorMsg
              )
              values
              (
                  @Dlr_Sap_Code,
                  @SerialNo,
                  @saledate,
                  @Remark,
                  @flag,
                  @DealerRemark,
                  @SerialRemark,
                  @SaleDateRemark
              );
              select
                  DealerCode,
                  ProductSerialNumber,
                  SecondarySaleDate,
                  Remarks,
                  IsValid,
                  DealerCodeErrorMsg,
                  SerialNumberErrorMsg,
                  SaleDateErrorMsg
              from #tempShow")
            .ToList();

        var resultModels = _mapper.Map<List<ResultModel>>(sqlResults);

        return resultModels;
    }
}
```